# Python Tkinter picture display

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import time
frame = Tk()
frame.title("Blackjack")
canvas = Canvas(frame, width=600, height=400)
canvas.grid()



background = PhotoImage(file="taust.gif")
card1 = PhotoImage(file="kaart1.gif")
img = canvas.create_image(300, 200, image=background)
img2 = canvas.create_image(300, 300, image=card1)
time.sleep(5)
canvas.delete(img)


frame.mainloop()
```

I want to display both pictures and after 5 seconds I want to delete one picture and keep the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `time.sleep` and just use `frame.after`.

The after method - `after(delay in ms, callback, *arguments)`

So, we can use `frame.after(5000, lambda: canvas.delete(img))`